# Get port of running python application

Tags: python, python-3.x, sockets, port

How to get the port of Python application currently running?

For example, in getting the IP of the computer the application is running, we have to run the code below:

```
 #Get Owner's IP
hostname = socket.gethostname()
owners_ip = socket.gethostbyname(hostname)
```

How about the specific port where the application is currently running?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
 s.bind(('', 0))
 owners_port = int(s.getsockname()[1])
```

Comment: This may answer your question (self answers such as this are encouraged), but a brief explanation of how it works may assist future visitors to the thread. Thanks!